# Loading .js file in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

on Chrome and Opera, the website works perfectly. When I open it in Firefox and IE it is not loading the ***.js*** files. My php code looks like this:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title id="titlebank">WEBSITE</title>
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="images/icon.ico">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/simple-line-icons.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/noty/packaged/jquery.noty.packaged.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/progressbar.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/kickstart.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="chat/chat.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="chat/chat.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: Errors in the console? Anything in the network panel?

Comment: try using the full URL path as HTTP://   ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js

Comment: It says that **chat** is not defined